# How to generate an array of dictionaries with a For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

The way I'm currently generating my array of dictionaries is very hard-wired in, and I'd rather not do it that way. `Top 3` doesn't necessarily have 3 items, I used that name for other reasons. For example, if I know `Top 3` will contain two items in addition to the search term, it will look like this:

```
                var top3Titles = [];
                var top3Prices = [];
                var top3ImgURLS = [];
                var top3ItemURLS = [];

                //where the title, price, and img url are sent over to the app
                matchCenterItems.forEach(function(item) {
                  var title = item.title[0];
                  var price = item.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__;
                  var imgURL = item.galleryURL[0];
                  var itemURL = item.viewItemURL[0];

                  top3Titles.push(title);
                  top3Prices.push(price);
                  top3ImgURLS.push(imgURL);
                  top3ItemURLS.push(itemURL);
                });

                // 10 results per MC Item, only showing 4 by default
                 var top3 = 
                {
                  "Top 3": 
                  [
                      {
                         "Search Term": searchTerm
                      },

                      { 
                        "Title": top3Titles[0], 
                        "Price": top3Prices[0], 
                        "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[0],
                        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[0]
                      },

                      {
                         "Title": top3Titles[1], 
                        "Price": top3Prices[1], 
                        "Image URL": top3ImgURLS[1],
                        "Item URL": top3ItemURLS[1] 
                      },
                  ]
                }; 

                return top3;
```

What I want to do instead is to have the number of dictionaries after the initial `Search Term` depend on how many `item` objects there are in the `matchCenterItems` array. I figured I could do this using a for loop, but I'm not entirely sure how to format it for this purpose. Rather than having separate arrays for titles, prices, etc, I want it to be an object with a title property for example.

Comment: The code you've exposed is very unclear, I must say. Why are you returning `top3` at the last line? Is this inside a function? Why aren't you showing the whole function then? Try to make your example more generic, it seems that you've only copied and pasted some production code that is not accomplishing very well your exemplification intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could initialize an array inside `top3` and add the objects while iterating over one or your arrays (top3Titles, top3Prices etc).

Like so:

```
var top3 = {'Top 3': [{'Search Term': searchTerm}]};

for (var i in top3Titles) {
  top3['Top 3'].push({
    'Title': top3Titles[i], 
    'Price': top3Prices[i], 
    'Image URL': top3ImgURLS[i],
    'Item URL': top3ItemURLS[i]
  });
}
```

Or, even better, you could replace everything you've posted with:

```
var top3 = {'Top 3': [{'Search Term': searchTerm}]};

matchCenterItems.forEach(function(item) {

top3['Top 3'].push(
  {
    'Title': item.title[0],
    'Price': item.sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice[0].__value__, 
    'Image URL': item.galleryURL[0],
    'Item URL':  item.viewItemURL[0]
  });
});

return top3;
```

But the point here is, the `return` belongs inside a function, as I've told you in my comment to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have good practice in JavaScript , but I can give you Demo of How to generate array of dict using for loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var arr=[];
var i;
var text="";
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    <!-- Creating 10 dictionary in array and initialise with some->
    <!--value to check->
   arr.push({firstName : "John"}) 
}

<!-- check that dict is working or not->
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
text=text+arr[i].firstName+'<br />'
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
text;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

you can run and check it ..